# Number guessing

Tags: javascript, numbers

> Remember a couple of exercises back we created a program capable of guessing numbers until the correct guess was reached?
>
> Now let's try to add a maximum number of tries to guess the target number. You have five tries, but if you guess it first, print a message and break out of the loop.

My code atm is:

```
var target = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
var tries = 5;

console.log(target);

tries = false;
while (guess);


   if (tries > 0) {
    tries--;
    if(tries === true) {

    }
}
```

how do I implement the maximum amount of guess limit?

Comment: while (guess); <-- why is there a semicolon?

Comment: `tries = 5; ... tries = false; ... if (tries > 0) ... tries--; if (tries === true)` - this definitely asks for another tutorial...

Comment: read about for loops : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check if guess is equal to target, I'd probably structure your loop something like this

```
while(tries > 0){
  if(guess === target) {
    console.log('You guessed the number!');
    break;
  } else {
    tries --;
    console.log('Incorrect, guessing again!');
  }
}
```

That should work, let me know if this is unclear and I'll try to answer any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); 
var guess= false; 
var tries=5; 
console.log(target);

while (tries>0) { 
    guess = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); 
    tries = tries - 1; 
    console.log(guess); 
    if(guess === target){ 
        console.log(guess); break; 
    } 
}
```